# pytest- getting cannot import name 'console_main'

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to run a python test with pytest but I'm getting error that "ImportError: cannot import name 'console_main' from 'pytest' (unknown location)"

I'm running the test using pytest but getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/func/bin/pytest", line 5, in <module>
    from pytest import console_main
ImportError: cannot import name 'console_main' from 'pytest' (unknown location)
```

and this is the code inside "/tmp/func/bin/pytest"

```
#!/tmp/func/bin/python3.8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from pytest import console_main
if __name__ == '__main__':
  sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
  sys.exit(console_main())
```

Comment: Try running it like: python3 -m pytest

Comment: didn't help, getting  error

/tmp/func/bin/python3: No module named pytest.__main__; 'pytest' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Answer (score 0):

you could try replacing

```
from pytest import console_main
```

with

```
from pytest import *
```